# How to speed up pytest

Tags: python, performance, pytest

Is there some way to speed up the repeated execution of `pytest`? It seems to spend a lot of time collecting tests, even if I specify which files to execute on the command line. I know it isn't a disk speed issue either since running pyflakes across all the .py files is very fast.

---

The various answers represent different ways pytest can be slow. They helped sometimes, did not in others. I'm adding one more answer that explains a common speed problem. But it's not possible to select "The" answer here.

Comment: Are you sure that the "collecting" phase is slow? Please, try run py.test with `--collectonly`.

Comment: Yes, it is collection that is slow. I can see the collect count start at 0, go to 2, then 7. I verified this again with `--collectonly`. Post collection the execution is almost immediate.

Comment: I have a project with more than 400 tests and collection phase is very fast. Additionally I have conftest.py which adds a lot of magic, a lot of `parametrize`s, fixtures, and `pytest_generate_tests` which make collecting slower, despite this collecting is fast in my case. Check that you do not have own code which interact with pytest collection phase and make it slower. If not, you can run profiler like line profiler to see which code is slow.

Comment: What code would interact with collection phase?  How long does collection take in your setup?

Comment: how long does importing all of your test modules take?

Comment: About 4-5 seconds, but I only have 2 test files. It also happens if I put the test file directly on the command-line (no searching).

Comment: I encountered a similar problem while running `py.test` in Cygwin. `py.test --collectonly` seems stuck for several seconds even before it actually starts collecting.

Comment: @famousgarkin cygwin is a different problem. I have a very minimal test file and directory to collect from. The time spent jumps between either 0.4 seconds or 11 seconds.

Answer (score 29):

Using the `norecursedirs` option in pytest.ini or tox.ini can save a lot of collection time, depending on what other files you have in your working directory. My collection time is roughly halved for a suite of 300 tests when I have that in place (0.34s vs 0.64s).

If you're already using [tox](http://tox.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) like I am, you just need to add the following in your tox.ini:

```
[pytest]
norecursedirs = docs *.egg-info .git appdir .tox
```

You can also add it in a free-standing `pytest.ini` file.

The pytest documentation has more details on [pytest configuration files](http://pytest.org/en/latest/customize.html).

Comment: Additionally (or instead) you should configure `testpaths`, i.e. `testpaths = src/tests`.  Then you do not need to skip `.git`, `.tox` etc.

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same problem where I was calling `pytest` at the root of my project and my tests were three subdirectories down. The collection was taking 6-7 seconds before 0.4 seconds of actual test execution.

My solution initially was to call `pytest` with the relative path to the tests:

```
pytest src/www/tests/
```

If doing that speeds up your collection also, you can add the relative path to the tests to the end of the `addopts` setting in your `pytest.ini` - eg:

```
[pytest]
addopts = --doctest-glob='test_*.md' -x src/www/tests/
```

This dropped the collection + execution time down to about a second and I could still just call `pytest` as I was before.

Comment: A better way is to configure this using `testpaths`, i.e. `testpaths = src/www/tests`.

Answer (score 6):

With [xdist](http://pytest.org/latest/xdist.html) you can parallelize pytest runs. It allows even to ship tests to remote machines. Depends on your setup it can speedup quite a bit :)

Comment: xdist does the collecting of tests on each of the remote machines, so although the test suite will probably faster, the collection won't be.

Answer (score 6):

For me, adding `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1` to my environment variables achieved a massive speedup! Note that I am using network drives which might be a factor.

- Windows Batch: `set PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1`
- Unix: `export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1`
- `subprocess.run`: Add keyword `env={'PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE': '1'}`
- PyCharm already set this variable automatically for me.

Note that the first two options only remain active for your current terminal session.

Answer (score 5):

In `bash`, try `{ find -name '*_test.py'; find -name 'test_*.py'; } | xargs pytest`.

For me, this brings total test time down to a fraction of a second.

Comment: I wonder why pytest doesn't use this method to scan the files first.

Answer (score 2):

In the special case where you are running under cygwin's python, its unix-style file handling is slow. See [pytest.py test very slow startup in cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768254/pytest-py-test-very-slow-startup-in-cygwin/30768365#30768365) for how to speed things up in that special situation.

Answer (score 2):

If you have some antivirus software running, try turning it off. I had this exact same problem. Collecting tests ran incredibly slow. It turned out to be my antivirus software (Avast) that was causing the problem. When I disabled the antivirus software, test collection ran about five times faster. I tested it several times, turning the antivirus on and off, so I have no doubt that was the cause in my case.

Edit: To be clear, I don't think antivirus should be turned off and left off. I just recommend turning it off temporarily to see if it is the source of the slow down. In my case, it was, so I looked for other antivirus solutions that didn't have the same issue.

Comment: It would be helpful if the people downvoting this answer added a comment stating why they are downvoting.

Comment: +1. This could be due to "antivirus always-on protection"  that monitors "suspicious" file access in the test folder: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-antivirus/configure-real-time-protection-windows-defender-antivirus

Comment: My suspicion is that people by default downvote turning off antivirus.

Comment: I suppose I should have been more clear that I don't advocate for leaving it off. Just that it may be the source of the problem and turning it off temporarily could expose the issue.

Comment: I would actually advocate for removing AV software. Update your systems regularly instead

Answer (score 1):

Pytest imports all modules in the `testpaths` directories to look for tests. The import itself can be slow. This is the same startup time you'd experience if you ran those tests directly, however, since it imports all of the files it will be a lot longer. It's kind of a worst-case scenario.

This doesn't add time to the whole test run though, as it would need to import those files anyway to execute the tests.

If you narrow down the search on the command line, to specific files or directories, it will only import those ones. This can be a significant speedup while running specific tests.

Speeding up those imports involves modifying those modules. The size of the module, and the transitive imports, slow down the startup. Additionally look for any code that is executed -- code outside of a function. That also needs to be executed during the test collection phase.