# Py.test collection phase taking very long

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm, pytest

I am really quite new to development in Python in general, let alone testing with pytest. My problem is that the pytest collection phase runs unusually slow. I am specifying the test directory which contains only a handful of files with only one file containing three tests. The collection takes pretty much a whole minute, after which the actual tests run in under a few seconds. I have looked at similar questions but couldn't find a solution. I don't think it matters (as py.test is slow even from the command line) but I am using the pycharm IDE. The OS is Ubuntu.

This may be relevant: If I terminate the process after a few seconds I usually end up with a stacktrace ending as follows:

```
<A FEW LINES OMITTED...>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/core.py", line 413, in __call__
    return self._docall(methods, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/core.py", line 424, in _docall
    res = mc.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/core.py", line 315, in execute
    res = method(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/helpconfig.py", line 27, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    config = __multicall__.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/core.py", line 315, in execute
    res = method(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 636, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    self.parse(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 747, in parse
    self._preparse(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 709, in _preparse
    self._initini(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 704, in _initini
    self.inicfg = getcfg(args, ["pytest.ini", "tox.ini", "setup.cfg"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 861, in getcfg
    if exists(p):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 848, in exists
    return path.check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py/_path/local.py", line 352, in check
    return exists(self.strpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 18, in exists
    os.stat(path)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Or sometimes...

```
<STACK TRACE...>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py/_iniconfig.py", line 50, in __init__
    f = open(self.path)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Maybe one of the two last calls before the KeyboardInterrupt is very slow?

Please do ask for more detail should you require it!

Cheers!

Comment: Going by that stacktrace it's trying to find the project root.  Could you show the layout of the files in your project and also show the exact py.test command you invoke as well as which directory you invoke this from?

Comment: > This may be relevant: If I terminate the process after a few seconds ... Yes, I think it is relevant. The related question [how to speed up py test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417546/how-to-speed-up-py-test) gives suggestions for how to speed py.test that seem relevant given your stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

Add `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1` to your environment variables!

- Windows Batch: `set PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1`
- Unix: `export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1`
- `subprocess.run`: Add keyword `env={'PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE': '1'}`

Note that the first two options are only valid for your current terminal session.

---

Here is how I found this out: `pytest` **was being unusably slow from the command line, but working fine from within PyCharm**. Copying the PyCharm command into cmd.exe (executes a small helper script) also was unusuably slow. Thus I printed out the environ variables at `os.environ` and tried it with that -- and it was fast! Then I eliminated each one-by-one.

Comment: I am experiencing the opposite. It runs faster from command line than running pytest in pycharm.  It started after installying cython extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My fix was to set the `Working directory` setting in the `Run/Debug Configuration`  to the folder where `manage.py` is located.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was based off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23318407/3977093), where I did `pytest dir/to/tests` and it skipped the collection step entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Having a large number of files in a sub-directory can cause slow test collection, even non-Python files like images and PDFs. See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735790/py-test-k-collecting-tests-takes-too-much-time/76332156#76332156).