# py.test -k: collecting tests takes too much time

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

If I do `Run Unittest .... test_foo` in `PyCharm` it takes quite long to run the test, since all tests get collected first. PyCharm uses `py.test -k` to run the test.

Since we have more than 1000 tests, collecting them takes some time (about 1.2 seconds). Often the test itself needs less time to execute!

Since I use this very often, I want to speed this up.

Any idea how to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to own question:

I installed pyCharm again (for other reasons) and now it uses utrunner.py.

It is much faster if I run `Run 'Unittest test_foo'`, since not this does not collect all tests before running the test.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Having a large number of files in a sub-directory can cause slow test collection. These might be images or PDFs - they don't need to be Python files.

If that's the case, you can ignore the relevant directories with pytest's `norecursedirs` configuration option. For example, to ignore the `node_modules` directory (always a good idea) as well as a `media` directory, create a `pytest.ini` file like this:

```
[pytest]
# From ".*" to "venv" are pytest defaults.
norecursedirs = .* build dist CVS _darcs {arch} *.egg venv node_modules media
```

As you can see from the defaults above, pytest already ignores directories and sub-directories beginning with ".", so focus on finding other directories with large numbers of files. See [counting files in sub-directories](https://superuser.com/a/474339).

Answer (score 0):

you can overcome the speed problem by calling it with `--collectonly` or by using  the relative path like

`py.test src/www/tests/`

You can see more solutions on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417546/how-to-speed-up-py-test)