# pytest takes a long time to collect tests

Tags: pytest

I have a small project with 1 test that takes a long time to collect. I've logstamped the collections and collection reports. Between 22:51:59 and 22:52:04, I'm not sure what's happening, but that's where the (idle?) pause is occuring.

```
[pytest]
testpaths = myproject/tests
python_files = *.py
addopts = -s
norecursedirs = docs *.egg-info .git appdir .tox __pycache__ .cache

root@0d696173168f:/var/www/myproject# pytest myproject/tests/redis/
================================= test session starts =================================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-3.0.3, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /var/www/myproject, inifile: pytest.ini
22:51:59: collection started
22:51:59: collecting file: /var/www/myproject/myproject/tests/redis/__init__.py
22:51:59: collecting file: /var/www/myproject/myproject/tests/redis/pubsub.py
collecting 0 items22:51:59: collection report: <CollectReport '' lenresult=2 outcome='passed'>
22:51:59: collection started
collecting 0 items22:52:04: collection report: <CollectReport 'myproject/tests/redis/__init__.py' lenresult=0 outcome='passed'>
22:52:04: collection started
22:52:04: collection started
collecting 0 items22:52:04: collection report: <CollectReport 'myproject/tests/redis/pubsub.py::RedisTest' lenresult=0 outcome='passed'>
22:52:04: collection started
22:52:04: collected item: <TestCaseFunction 'test_pass'>
collecting 1 items22:52:04: collection report: <CollectReport 'myproject/tests/redis/pubsub.py::RegisterTests' lenresult=1 outcome='passed'>
collecting 1 items22:52:04: collection report: <CollectReport 'myproject/tests/redis/pubsub.py' lenresult=2 outcome='passed'>
collected 1 items

myproject/tests/redis/pubsub.py .

============================== 1 passed in 5.64 seconds ===============================
```

Comment: I had a similar problem - it turns out, that I've added very time intensive calculations in the module, that had the functions, that I've been importing in tests. Remember, import in Python _runs_ the actual file. Therefore it's important to guard the _main_ code with the `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement.

Comment: Not an answer, but I've noticed a similar issue lately from time to time and realized it coincides with problems in an OS upgrade to Big Sur on Mac.  Long story short, the networking is available, but non-functional.  If I disable networking, there is no pause.  Once I fix the networking, there is no pause.  But if the pytest suite thinks there is a network it'll spend 30 seconds trying to do $something.  Haven't figured out what yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say anything specific without looking at test code.

I recommend to make sure that in test modules you have only test functions/classes and/or fixtures. Reason is that any "unwrapped" code in test modules will be executed by pytest at collection phase.

Answer (score 0):

Having a large number of files in a sub-directory (even non-Python files like images and PDFs) can cause slow test collection. See this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735790/py-test-k-collecting-tests-takes-too-much-time/76332156#76332156).