# How to profile very slow speed of pytest collection?

Tags: pytest

Running a simple `pytest -k nomatchingtestfilter` takes around 2-3 seconds on my Ubuntu 22.04 machine just on the `collecting...` stage.

I have custom `pytest_collection` and `pytest_collection_modify_items` functions in `conftest.py`. I added a `print(start - end)` log inside them (`start` and `end` are set to `time.time()`). From this log, I know they only take a few milliseconds to execute. I do not have any other user-defined functions related to pytest collection.

Therefore, I need to profile the collection step to understand why exactly it is taking 2-3 seconds to collect a few hundred parameterized tests.

I tried `pytest-profiling`, but it does not help because it starts profiling after the collection is done.

**Question:** What is the way to profile the pytest collection step so as to find bottlenecks and improve their speed?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a specific suggestion for profiling, but I have found that a large amount of files (even non-Python files) within your project can cause slow collection. See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735790/py-test-k-collecting-tests-takes-too-much-time/76332156#76332156)

Comment: (Sorry for the late comment but...) Your suggestion did improve my collection time from 2.5s to 0.6s. I am leaving the question open because I'd still be interested in knowing how to profile the time taken.