# Pytest startup seems long ("pytest -h" takes 11 seconds)

Tags: python, pytest

The following commands take ~5-10s real time (only ~0.01s sys time):

- `time pytest --version`
- `time pytest -h`
- `time python  venv/Lib/site-packages/pytest/__main__.py -h`
- `time find tests/ -name "test_*.py" | xargs pytest --collectonly --quiet`

Is this normal? Can we speed it up?

---

This question might be related to [How to speed up pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417546/how-to-speed-up-pytest). However, there they discuss options to reduce the collection time, which is another issue if I understand correctly.

//EDIT: The virtual environment contains several pytest plugins (see list below). I'll try a fresh installation and see if one of those is the culprit

```
pytest-cases>=3
pytest-check>=1
pytest-instafail
pytest-cov
pytest-xdist
```

//EDIT: Running `python -m cProfile -s cumulative venv/Lib/site-packages/pytest/__main__.py --version` yields the following function calls (only those with cumulative time > 1s). To my surprise, it seems to access the source code files such as `segmentation.py` even for such a call?

```
     7395628 function calls (7059798 primitive calls) in 6.028 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   2514/1    0.033    0.000    6.034    6.034 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    6.034    6.034 __main__.py:1(<module>)
  2229/28    0.012    0.000    5.951    0.213 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:986(_find_and_load)
  2068/28    0.006    0.000    5.951    0.213 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:956(_find_and_load_unlocked)
  1962/31    0.007    0.000    5.939    0.192 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:650(_load_unlocked)
  2643/30    0.001    0.000    5.914    0.197 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:211(_call_with_frames_removed)
  1669/28    0.004    0.000    5.890    0.210 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:842(exec_module)
        1    0.000    0.000    5.877    5.877 __init__.py:178(console_main)
        1    0.000    0.000    5.877    5.877 __init__.py:130(main)
        1    0.000    0.000    5.875    5.875 __init__.py:297(_prepareconfig)
    75/55    0.000    0.000    5.850    0.106 manager.py:90(_hookexec)
    75/55    0.000    0.000    5.850    0.106 manager.py:84(<lambda>)
    75/55    0.000    0.000    5.850    0.106 callers.py:157(_multicall)
      4/2    0.000    0.000    5.848    2.924 hooks.py:272(__call__)
        1    0.000    0.000    5.848    5.848 __init__.py:999(pytest_cmdline_parse)
        1    0.000    0.000    5.848    5.848 __init__.py:1275(parse)
        1    0.000    0.000    5.843    5.843 __init__.py:1149(_preparse)
    186/9    0.000    0.000    5.768    0.641 __init__.py:109(import_module)
    192/9    0.000    0.000    5.768    0.641 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1002(_gcd_import)
    31/13    0.001    0.000    5.760    0.443 rewrite.py:130(exec_module)
      202    0.005    0.000    5.694    0.028 __init__.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    5.652    5.652 __init__.py:1068(pytest_load_initial_conftests)
        1    0.000    0.000    5.652    5.652 __init__.py:474(_set_initial_conftests)
        1    0.000    0.000    5.652    5.652 __init__.py:505(_try_load_conftest)
        3    0.000    0.000    5.650    1.883 __init__.py:515(_getconftestmodules)
        1    0.000    0.000    5.649    5.649 __init__.py:552(_importconftest)
        1    0.000    0.000    5.648    5.648 pathlib.py:451(import_path)
        1    0.000    0.000    5.645    5.645 conftest.py:1(<module>)
        2    0.000    0.000    5.516    2.758 segmentation.py:1(<module>)
        2    0.000    0.000    4.318    2.159 object_statistics.py:1(<module>)
        5    0.000    0.000    3.473    0.695 color.py:300(_decorator)
        5    0.000    0.000    3.473    0.695 decorators.py:191(wrap)
  737/294    0.002    0.000    3.407    0.012 compiler_lock.py:32(_acquire_compile_lock)
    22/12    0.000    0.000    3.074    0.256 compiler.py:660(compile_extra)
       10    0.000    0.000    3.001    0.300 gufunc.py:62(add)
       10    0.000    0.000    3.001    0.300 ufuncbuilder.py:235(add)
       10    0.000    0.000    3.000    0.300 ufuncbuilder.py:169(_compile_element_wise_function)
       10    0.000    0.000    3.000    0.300 ufuncbuilder.py:103(compile)
       10    0.001    0.000    2.999    0.300 ufuncbuilder.py:122(_compile_core)
    30/12    0.000    0.000    2.928    0.244 compiler.py:422(compile_extra)
    30/12    0.000    0.000    2.924    0.244 compiler.py:487(_compile_bytecode)
    30/12    0.000    0.000    2.924    0.244 compiler.py:445(_compile_core)
    30/12    0.002    0.000    2.917    0.243 compiler_machinery.py:320(run)
  720/288    0.008    0.000    2.911    0.010 compiler_machinery.py:257(_runPass)
 2160/864    0.002    0.000    2.902    0.003 compiler_machinery.py:261(check)
    30/21    0.002    0.000    2.018    0.096 typed_passes.py:365(run_pass)
  813/174    0.001    0.000    1.636    0.009 {built-in method builtins.__import__}
    30/21    0.000    0.000    1.351    0.064 lowering.py:133(lower)
20224/18974    0.016    0.000    1.326    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1017(_handle_fromlist)
    12932    0.971    0.000    1.097    0.000 ffi.py:149(__call__)
    30/21    0.000    0.000    1.016    0.048 lowering.py:184(lower_normal_function)
    30/21    0.000    0.000    1.000    0.048 lowering.py:201(lower_function_body)
```

Comment: This is not normal, do you have any plugins configured? You can use py-spy to get a flamegraph of pytest launch performance https://github.com/benfred/py-spy

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your answer @vinzBad!

It seems the pytest-extensions are not the culprit. Installed all of them in a blank repository. They only increase the time for `pytest --version` from 0.3s to at most 0.5s.

However, as the cProfile above demonstrated, even for `pytest --version` all source files seem to be imported. And the import just seems to take ~5s as determined by `time python -c "import segmentation"`. This might be a non-optimizable time, since many libraries are imported. Definitely not a pytest issue though.